# Ncurses "initscr()" causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I am currently working on a project, where I have to implement a snake game which compiles just fine on itself with `g++`, the problem is when I try to integrate it into the greater project which compiles using `CMake` it throws a segmentation fault, even though I narrowed the whole main file down to being

```
 #include <ncurses.h>
 int main(){
     initscr();
     return 0;
 }
```

I have no clue why this is happening and haven't been able to find a solution through other fora. I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 and cmake version 3.5.1 as well as ncurses5 v6.

Comment: Use your debugger, and step through the code.

Comment: @RichardCritten There's not much to step through here.

Comment: Do you get the segfault too if you compile *just* this source file into a program? If you do, it sounds like a problem with your set-up, not your program. If you don't, see if you can figure out which additional source file causes the problem.

Comment: @Richard - I tried running the program with gdb, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @hvd - If I compile just that snip `g++ -o test testmain.cpp -lncurses` it compiles fine. And the whole game itself compiles fine with this. So I suspect there is some issue with CMake and curses, even though I have included it in the CMakelists.txt as it should.

Comment: I found something that helped the problem, but it doesn't make sense to me. In the CMakeLists.txt I had `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( Enable ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib::dlib)`, and changing it to `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( Enable ${OpenCV_LIBS})` solves the core dump problem even though it is totally unrelated to the snake game...